# Issues with commons-logging while running webapp via xsbt-web-plugin

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm trying to use jcl-over-slf4j to handle logging for a few dependencies (commons-logging is brought in via Dispatch, Authorize.net and Rackspace CloudFiles - anything that uses httpclient...). Everything works fine when running outside of sbt, but I receive a `NoClassDefFoundError` when running via `container:start`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

I've excluded commons-logging via `ivyXML`.

Some config info:

```
object BuildSettings {
  import Resolvers._

  val buildOrganization = "myproject"
  val buildVersion      = "1.0"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.9.0-1"

  val buildSettings: Seq[Project.Setting[_]] = {
    Defaults.defaultSettings ++
    webSettings ++
    (resolvers += maven2) ++
    (scanDirectories in Compile := Nil) ++
    (ivyXML := Dependencies.globalExclusions) ++
    (libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.webapp) ++
    Seq(
      name         := "MyProject",
      organization := buildOrganization,
      version      := buildVersion,
      scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion
    )
  }
}

object Resolvers {
  val maven2 = "Java.net Maven2 Repo" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
  val scalaToolsSnapshots = "Scala Tools Snapshot" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/"
  val scalaToolsReleases = "Scala Tools Releases" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases"
}

object Dependencies {

  val liftVersion = "2.4-M5"
  val jettyVersion = "7.4.5.v20110725"

  val lift = Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile->default" withSources(),
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile->default" withSources(),
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-widgets" % liftVersion % "compile->default" withSources()
  )

  val jetty = "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % jettyVersion % "container"
  val servlet = "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided"

  val scalate = "org.fusesource.scalate" % "scalate-core" % "1.5.3" % "compile"

  val slf4j = "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.6.4" % "compile"
  val jclSlf4j = "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j" % "1.6.4" % "compile"

  val commonsValidator = "commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.3.1" % "compile"

  val dispatch = "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.5" % "compile"
  val dispatchJson = "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-lift-json" % "0.8.5" % "compile"

  val quartz = "org.quartz-scheduler" % "quartz" % "2.1.2" % "compile" withSources()

  val junit = "junit" % "junit" % "4.5" % "test->default"
  val specs = "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.7.1" % "test->default"

  val postgres = "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-702.jdbc4" % "runtime->default"

  val globalExclusions = <dependencies>
    <exclude org="commons-logging" module="commons-logging" />
  </dependencies>

  val webapp = Seq(
    jetty, servlet,
    scalate,
    slf4j, jclSlf4j,
    commonsValidator,
    dispatch, dispatchJson,
    quartz,
    junit, specs,
    postgres
  ) ++ lift

}
```

When running outside of sbt, I'm using:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl
```

and have placed commons-logging and log4j jars in /etc.
I'm also excluding log4j jar via my ivyXml before I package the webapp.
http://articles.qos.ch/classloader.html

**EDIT 1 (some additional error info):**

```
Message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:159)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:178)
dispatch.ConfiguredHttpClient.<init>(ConfiguredHttpClient.scala:11)
dispatch.thread.ThreadSafeHttpClient.<init>(thread.scala:34)
dispatch.thread.Safety$class.make_client(thread.scala:16)
dispatch.Http$.make_client(Http.scala:29)
dispatch.Http$.make_client(Http.scala:29)
dispatch.BlockingHttp$class.$init$(Http.scala:39)
dispatch.Http.<init>(Http.scala:21)
dispatch.Http$.<init>(Http.scala:29)
dispatch.Http$.<clinit>(Http.scala)
...
Caught and thrown by:
Message:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:159)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:178)
dispatch.ConfiguredHttpClient.<init>(ConfiguredHttpClient.scala:11)
dispatch.thread.ThreadSafeHttpClient.<init>(thread.scala:34)
dispatch.thread.Safety$class.make_client(thread.scala:16)
dispatch.Http$.make_client(Http.scala:29)
dispatch.Http$.make_client(Http.scala:29)
dispatch.BlockingHttp$class.$init$(Http.scala:39)
dispatch.Http.<init>(Http.scala:21)
dispatch.Http$.<init>(Http.scala:29)
dispatch.Http$.<clinit>(Http.scala)
```

Comment: What if you add `commons-logging` to your `libraryDependencies` under the `container` config (so it will be limited only to the `container:start` usage)?

Comment: Would that be something like `libraryDependencies in container.Configuration += Dependencies.commonsLogging` where `val commonsLogging = "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1"`? This doesn't seem to work... I thought that with jcl-over-slf4j I didn't need commons-logging...

Comment: Try this: `val commonsLogging = "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1" % "container->default"` -- then add it to `val webapp = Seq(commonsLogging, ...`

Comment: Ok. That definitely added the commons-logging jar (I can see that it's being loaded from /Users/andrewmullins/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar but I still get the same error...